# How to maintain record history on table with one-to-many relationships?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, one-to-many

I have a "services" table for detailing services that we provide. Among the data that needs recording are several small one-to-many relationships (all with a foreign key constraint to the service_id) such as:

```
service_owners -- user_ids responsible for delivery of service
service_tags -- e.g. IT, Records Management, Finance
customer_categories -- ENUM value
provider_categories -- ENUM value
software_used -- self-explanatory
```

The problem I have is that I want to keep a history of updates to a service, for which I'm using an update trigger on the table, that performs an insert into a history table matching the original columns. However, if a normalized approach to the above data is used, with separate tables and foreign keys for each one-to-many relationship, any update on these tables will not be recognised in the history of the service.

Does anyone have any suggestions? It seems like I need to store child keys in the service table to maintain the integrity of the service history. Is a delimited text field a valid approach here or, as I am using postgreSQL, perhaps arrays are also a valid option? These feel somewhat dirty though!

Thanks.

Comment: Your history table does not have to be normalized.  In order to be a true history, it has to contain the values from your categories at the time the history row was written.

Answer (score 2):

If your table is:

```
create table T (
    ix int identity primary key,
    val nvarchar(50)
)
```

And your history table is:

```
create table THistory (
    ix int identity primary key,
    val nvarchar(50),
    updateType char(1), -- C=Create, U=Update or D=Delete
    updateTime datetime,
    updateUsername sysname
)
```

Then you just need to put an update trigger on all tables of interest. You can then find out what the state of any/all of the tables were at any point in history, to determine what the relationships were at that time.

Comment: Hi. This is something I have considered, but wouldn't this then require insert-only child tables with start_date and end_date columns? (The historical data of the child tables is then begin stored alongside the active data, therein swelling the table). Is this definitely preferable to an ENUM array or int array column in the service table itself? Thanks.

Comment: Just have an active table, and a history table. History tables don't require any relationships, they just hold historical copies of every row of the active table. The active tables don't reference the history tables whatsoever. Whenever the active table is updated, the trigger ensures the history table gets a new row with the new data.

Comment: I would think that most of the columns in the table Thistory should be set to NOT NULL. (depending on your use case of course!)

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid using arrays in any database whenever possible.

I don't like updates for the exact reason you are saying here...you lose information as it's over written.  My answer is quite simple...don't update.  Not sure if you're at a point where this can be implemented...but if you can I'd recommend using the main table itself to store historical (no need for a second set of history tables).

Add a column to your main header table called 'active'.  This can be a character or a bit (0 is off and 1 is on).  Then it's a bit of trigger magic...when an update is preformed, you insert a row into the table identical to the record being over-written with a status of '0' (or inactive) and then update the existing row (this process keeps the ID column on the active record the same, the newly inserted record is the inactive one with a new ID).

This way no data is ever lost (admittedly you are storing quite a few rows...) and the history can easily be viewed with a select where active = 0.

The pain here is if you are working on something already implemented...every existing query that hits this table will need to be updated to include a check for the active column.  Makes this solution very easy to implement if you are designing a new system, but a pain if it's a long standing application.  Unfortunately existing reports will include both off and on records (without throwing an error) until you can modify the where clause